# Laravel create multiple user tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables - users and user_attributes.
During registration user I would like to not only enter the user in the user table but also create his attributes.

AuthController

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return UserAttribute::create([
            'user_id' => $data['id'],  // Undefined index: id
            'lvl' => 0,
            'exp' => 0,
            'currency' => 500,
            'premium_currency' => 5,
        ]);
    }
```

How do I get user_id?
PS: I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: the simplest way would be to do `$user = User::create([...]). then UserAttribute::create(['user_id' => $user->id]);` but you should really be using Eloquent relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: the data is correctly add to the database, but it shows the [error](https://scr.hu/46cd/79jp6), [code](https://scr.hu/46cd/7nbjn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this 
    $user =new User;
    $user->thing1 = 12;
    $user->thing2 =32;
    $user->save();

And now as soon as you have called the save method you can get the id by doing

```
$user->id;
```

Remember! It will only work after you have called the save method.

Also remember to replace my data with your data.

For further info and explanation see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-inserts

Best of luck!

Comment: the data is correctly add to the database, but it shows the error [error](http://scr.hu/46cd/79jp6) [code](http://scr.hu/46cd/7nbjn)

Comment: I can with 100% safety say that this is not in anyway related to your insert. This is a mess up somewhere else im afraid i can't help you without seeing some more code pf various controllers and models :-)

Comment: I didn't return $user at the end :P